# You are a beta tester for this app not appearing in Google play store

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, google-play-console

1. I have uploaded an apk to alpha channel
2. I have added email Id to a closed testing group.
3. I have distributed opt-in URL to those email id's and they have clicked "become a tester" button.
4. Those email id's get my latest version of apk (the version uploaded to alpha channel). Alpha channel has 2.1.0.1 version while production has 2.0, so the user can see the version as 2.1.0.1.

But when I go to play store to this app "You're a beta tester for this app. Awesome!", this message is not appearing.

While I did same steps for another app a few months back and for that app I can see this message.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue. I uploaded a new apk on alpha channel with double checking everything and it worked. Thanks :)